# Model of an FPGA

Tags: fpga

Is there a publicly available model of an FPGA? A performance model or a functional model or something similar. Basically, I am looking for something that I can play with (as in, change its parameters like the number of logic blocks in it or the size of memory in it, etc.) to see how the resulting FPGA would behave (as in, whether a given HDL design would fit on the FPGA with new parameters or not, or what impact would the new parameters have on the usage of the FPGA).

Comment: You can just take the development software of any FPGA vendor. It has all the tools and models you require for free.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you explain a little more though? For example, if I consider Xilinx, I do have their Vivado tool. I have my HDL design and I am able to synthesize/implement it on a specific FPGA that Xilinx provides using Vivado. But what I want to do is to change the parameters of the FPGA (instead of picking a different FPGA from the list provided by Xilinx) and then see how the synthesis/implementation goes. I hope that helps clarify what I am looking to do.

Comment: I have the strong feeling your are on the wrong track. *" change the parameters of the FPGA"* does not make sense as you are talking about HDL and then there is almost no difference between FPGAs other then the amount of logic they offer. I find that a design only gets different (mostly in timing) if it is a fast design and you go above 80%-90% utlisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of virtual FPGA architectures :)

Have a look at the Verilog to Routing (VTR) tool [1].

It's an active open source [2] academic toolkit which enables you to elaborate a Verilog input down to a placed and routed design - on your own architecture. It cannot be (out-of-the-box) used for a bitstream generation targeting a comercialy available FPGA, but there is a full access to all the details of the virtual FPGA architecture, which can also be modified.

The primary purpose of this tools is to offer a "playground" for FPGA architecture and CAD tools studies, so it can be a good starting point to your adventure.

[1] https://verilogtorouting.org/

[2] https://github.com/verilog-to-routing/vtr-verilog-to-routing

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I will look into the links you've mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on the vendor of the FPGA that you intend to program.

For example if you go with Microsemi (used to be Actel) and download their FPGA tool, Libero, you can by using their free license (Silver) do simulations using a ModelSim plugin inside the tool.

Comment: I have mostly used Xilinx. But can we change the parameters of an FPGA (say change the number of logic blocks in an FPGA from 5000 to 5001) and then synthesize/implement a piece of HDL/RTL for that "new non-existent experimental" FPGA in Actel/Microsemi's tools?

Comment: Afaik that is not possible. You have to pick from existing devices (to my knowledge).